# Из .ру в .ехе из фотографиями

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

Я делаю игру на pygame и когда я сделал саму игру я понял одну проблему, я не могу сделать из него .ехе файл, что бы отправить игру друзьям у которых нет питона, и я собираю его через pyinstaller, на нем я уже делал .ехе файл, но вот сделать игру не могу, мне выдает ошибку, что не нашло фотографию заднего фона.
Как это можно решить, заранее спасибо=)

Comment: Мы гадать должны какая ошибка, какой код?

Comment: когда создается .ехе файл фотографии не идут вместе из кодом

Comment: как можно добавить фотографии вместе из .ехе файлом, что бы они работали, в отдельную папку и делать zip или еще что-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для начала, ты должен понимать, что exe файл не включает в себя все фотографии, бд и прочее. (то-есть друзьям ты должен скидывать не exe, а всю папку с проектом.
2. Следовательно все файла игры (включая .py) должны находится в одной папке. Запусти и проверь, что связи между папками не нарушились, что все модули установлены. Отчисти папку от ненужных файлов, только не трогай файлы и папки проекта: venv, .idea, **pycache** (если есть)
3. в папке проекта открываешь cmd и пишешь следующие команды:
   `pip install pyinstaller` (если нету)
   Далее выполняем следующую команду:

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py`
Где main.py — главный файл твоего приложения.

Что делают модификаторы:

`onefile` собирает программу в один exe-файл. Это удобно, если программа небольшая, у нее мало графических, аудио и прочих файлов, не относящихся к программному коду.
`noconsole` Если не писать этот модификатор, то, кроме окна программы будет открываться Python-консоль. Иногда, например, для отладки, удобно оставлять командную строку для вывода системных сообщений, при передаче же программы клиенту консоль обычно скрывают.

Все должно получится.

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно будет скидывать отдельно ехе файл и фотографии к нему, но у меня вообщем не работает фотография, тоесь она не подключена к ехе файлу
И когда я вписываю --noconsole при запуске ехе файла мне выдает ошибку, поетому я не пользуюсь ним

Comment: я вроде все нормально описал.... ты скидываешь друзьям не exe и картинке, а всю папку с проектом. Короче, пришли ошибку, и по возможности сам проект.

Comment: Еще раз попробую объяснить суть, твой код, когда загружает какой-то файл, он обращается к нему по локальному пути (если ты все сделал правильно), то есть не ```C:/programs/my_game/imgs/picture.png```, а ```imgs/picture.png```. то-есть если ты передвинешь один файл относительно другого, то твой .py его не найдет. то-же самое и с exe. в нем прописаны те же пути, что и в твоем коде, поэтому когда ты отправляешь другу игру, отправляй ее папкой, в которой правильно лежит exe и картинки. Я не знаю что-тут можно еще объяснять, мне кажется, что я уже все что можно рассказал.

Comment: Да, вы все правильно обьясняете, но просто я не много не понимаю, я делал ехе файл в один(--onefile) и кидал к файлу папку img в которой у меня все фотографии, но он все равно не работает, возможно все таки ошибка в не правильном построении кода, и он обращяется не так, если вам не сложно можете обьяснить как сделать правильный путь к файлу=)